# Access request parameters in URL in ember page

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js

I am using Ember.js in my application. In a .jsp page I have a button and when I click on the button I call the `url = "emberapp/myproject/routename?isFromJSP=true&data=[1,2]"`.

This correctly routes to my `routename`.

The problem is, I want to read the boolean parameter (isFromJSP) and list parameter (data) in my controller or route. How to do so?

PS:I know to use window.location.href but it is not returning the current page in my EMBER init function. I am using AJAX calls to get data for my ember page in the init function and I want to pass these request parameters as request json objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: its not a duplicate. Read the question carefully. When i use window.location.href in my ember page, its returning previous page's url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout the [query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/routing/query-params/#toc-toggle).

Basically you can do this in your controller:

```
queryParams: ['isFromJSP', 'data'],
isFromJSP: false,
data: [],
```

Next you can either use this for computed properties, or access them on the `params` hash passed to the routes `model` hook. If you do the later consider to add this to your route:

```
queryParams: {
  isFromJSP: {
    refreshModel: true
  },
  data: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
},
```

this will enforce that a change to the query params will reload the model (and will do a full transition).

Comment: If i am using two ember pages to pass parameters, then i can use this query params. But my scenario is different. I cant use the queryparams as i m transferring the control from a .jsp page.

Comment: how can i access them in my controller? I cant get the way you specified in the code. Could you give me an example?

Comment: in my params map, i am not getting these passed values.

Comment: Then something is wrong. This should work. [See this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f547f9e7bba972a92b11eae5b37348ca?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C), just enter something like `/?data=[1,2]` to the "virtual" url.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it! One more doubt. When i reload my ember page, my route is changed twice and the url is changed like "#/emberapp/checkQuery/checkQuery/function". But if i use the function transitionTo() the url is maintained as expected "#/emberapp/checkQuery/function". Could you guide me here??

Comment: you do something wrong. But I notice the `#` in the beginning. Are you using hash locations? Because then you have to use hash locations for the link as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The thing is, when I use query params, it is set to default for the entire session. I want it to change periodically. Is it compulsory to send them in all routes? Otherwise will it take the previous value as default value/

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If you want to discuss this, maybe you should checkout the ember community slack help channel